# I don't get importing Maven Project options

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to Java

I have been trying to compile my open source application

with provided steps

```
Import Project from Maven
1. Start IntelliJ IDEa.
2. In the "Quick Start" menu, select "Import Project".
This will open a "Select File or Directory to Import" dialog.
3. Browse to your local cTakes repository root directory and select the pom.xml file.
4. Click "Ok".
This will open an "Import Project from Maven" dialog.
5. Make sure the "Search for projects recursively" box is selected, just in case any cTakes modules are not in the pom.
6. Make sure that "Create IntelliJ IDEa modules for aggregator projects" is not selected.
If you plan to add new module, 'disable' a present cTakes module or make other changes to the main pom.xml, check the "Import Maven projects automatically" box.
See also: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-importing.html
7. Make sure that "Create module rgoups for multi-module Maven projects" is not selected.
8. Make sure that "Keep source and test folders on reimport is selected.
9. Make sure that "Exclude build directory (%PROJECT_ROOT%/target)" is selected.
10. Make sure that "Use Maven output directories" is selected.
11. Make sure that the "Generated sources folders" option "Detect automatically" is selected.
12. For the "Phase to be used for folders update" the default option "process-resources" should be fine.
13. For the "Automatically download" options, you may select what you like, but be wary that if broken code has been checked in you may need to revert manually.
14. The default "Dependency types" are fine.
15. Click "Environment settings...".
This will open a dialog that can be used to set options about the Maven environment.
16. The default maven environment settings should be fine. If $M2_HOME is not set in your environment you may select a "Maven home directory", but it is better to set $M2_HOME in your environment.
17. Click "Next".
This will inspect the cTakes Maven settings and search for profiles. It should display a dialog with the possible cTakes profiles.
If you plan to run the UIMA CVD or CPE then select the appropriate profile. Neither is necessary
18. Click "Next".
This will open an "Import" dialog with the current version of cTakes displayed.
19. Click "Next".
This will open a dialog allowing you to select a Java SDK version.
20. Click the "+" button in the top left.
This will display a drop-down box with options for an SDK.
21. Select "JDK".
This will open a dialog to select a Java JDK directory.
22. Navigate to a directory with a JDK version 1.8 or later and click "Ok". 
This will display a listing of the file paths associated with the selected JDK.
23. Click "Next".

24. Click "Ok/Next"
The project will load. This may take a while.
25. Important: If you are asked about adding any .iml files to svn, click "No".

26. You should now see the full cTakes project structure in IntelliJ.
```

I get everything up to step 4

but step 5 does not exist in my case

I mean in step 5

> **5. Make sure the "Search for projects recursively" box is selected, just in case any cTakes modules are not in the pom.**

There are no options I get, it immediately takes me to the IntelliJ project

I get this screen

[image]

after I ckick finish , it takes me to this

[image]

Am I using older version? or doing something wrong?

[image]

***How to get the Maven options as the instructions suggested?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're in a unique position where the import and the recursive scanning of projects has Just Worked™ for your use case.

Given that IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 came out at the end of November 2019 and I'm not *reasonably* convinced that those instructions were written or revised between the end of November and now, it could easily be the case that the instructions you've seen are out of date.

The big thing to be sure of is that your subprojects also build.  On the right-hand side there, you have a list of Maven projects.  Any one of those should be subprojects.  Be sure that any Maven build command (e.g. `mvn clean install`) executes in the context of that subproject.